# Ada Access to parameterless procedure "wrong convention"

Tags: function-pointers, ada

I have the following binding:

```ada
function atexit(proc : access Procedure) return Integer with
    Import, Convention => C;
```

As well as the procedure:

```ada
procedure Exiting is
begin
    Put_Line("Exiting");
end Exiting;
```

When I try to call it like:

```ada
I : Integer := atexit(Exiting'Access);
```

it fails with `subprogram "Exited" has wrong convention`

however providing my own (incompatable) `atexit` which accepts a parameter, and modifying `Exiting` to use that same parameter, allows passing the procedure just fine.

So it seems like the issue is passing a parameterless procedure as an access type.

I've tried giving a named access type like

```ada
type Procedure_Access is access Procedure;
```

But the result is exactly the same.

How can I pass a parameterless procedure then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have forgotten the `Convention` aspects in the declarations of `Exiting` and `Procedure_Access`. The following works in GNAT CE 2018:

**foo.c**

```
int _atexit(void (*f)(void))
{
  (*f)();
  return 0;
}
```

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

procedure Main is

   type proc_ptr is access procedure
     with Convention => C;

   function atexit(proc : proc_ptr) return int
     with Import, Convention => C, Link_Name => "_atexit";


   procedure Exiting
     with Convention => C;      

   procedure Exiting is
   begin
      Put_Line("Exiting");
   end Exiting;


   I : Integer := Integer (atexit (Exiting'Access));

begin
   Put_Line("atexit returned " & I'Image);
end Main;
```

**default.gpr**

```
project Default is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.adb");
   for Languages use ("Ada", "C");

end Default;
```

**output**

```
Exiting
atexit returned  0
```

Comment: That was exactly it, oops!